# AVAudioSession.mode causes "Editor placeholder in source file" error while doing a migration from swift 3 to swift 4.2

Tags: swift, migration, avaudiosession

XCode 10.1 successfully performed the migration, but after I performed a Build some errors crept in. Here is one example:

```
func setPlayAndRecordMode() {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    if convertFromAVAudioSessionCategory(audioSession.category) == convertFromAVAudioSessionCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord) && convertFromAVAudioSessionMode(audioSession.mode) == convertFromAVAudioSessionMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.measurement) {
        return
    }

    do {
         try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category(rawValue: 
         convertFromAVAudioSessionCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord)), mode:  AVAudioSession.Mode) (**error message**: Editor placeholder in source file)

        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.measurement)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Any thoughts and suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your mode for example `moviePlayBack` , `spokenAudio` etc.. check a complete list [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/mode), as an example I passed `spokenAudio` on your line as shown below.

```
convertFromAVAudioSessionCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord)), mode:  AVAudioSession.Mode.spokenAudio)
```